# Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int. (in two places)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm getting this error

> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 102
>   Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.
>   The statement has been terminated.
>
> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 114
>   Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.
>   The statement has been terminated.

```
CREATE TABLE city(
 citycode int,
 city_name varchar(78)
 CONSTRAINT cityPK primary key(citycode)
 )

 CREATE TABLE workers(
 work_no int,
 NameW varchar(90),
 LastName varchar(30),
 ID int,
 phone varchar(50),
 citycode int,
 CONSTRAINT workerPK primary key(work_no),
 CONSTRAINT workerFK foreign key(citycode)
 REFERENCES city(citycode)
 )
 CREATE TABLE managers(
 manager_no int,
 Manager_name varchar(90),
 Manager_last varchar(90),
 city_code int,
 CONSTRAINT managerPK primary key(manager_no),
 CONSTRAINT managerFK1 foreign key(city_code)
 REFERENCES city(citycode)
 )

 CREATE TABLE mahlakot(
 no int,
 Mahlka_name varchar(50),
 Mahlka_type varchar(50),
 Manager_no int,
 CONSTRAINT mahlakotPK primary key(no),
 CONSTRAINT mahlakotFK1 foreign key(Manager_no)
 REFERENCES managers(manager_no)
 )

 CREATE TABLE products(
 Product_ID int,
 Prod_name varchar(89),
 Mahlka_no int,
 Prise money,
 CONSTRAINT productsPK PRIMARY KEY(Product_ID),
 CONSTRAINT productFK1 foreign key(Mahlka_no)
 REFERENCES mahlakot(no)
 )

 CREATE TABLE Coustmers(
 Cust_id int,
 Cust_name varchar(80),
 Cust_last varchar(80),
 Cust_date date,
 saled_by int,
 product_id int,
 CONSTRAINT CUSTPK PRIMARY KEY(Cust_id),
 CONSTRAINT CUSTFK1 FOREIGN KEY(saled_by)
 REFERENCES workers(work_no),
 CONSTRAINT CUSTFK2 FOREIGN KEY(product_id)
 REFERENCES products(Product_ID)
 )

 insert into city VALUES
 (800,'Haifa'),
 (802,'Akko'),
 (804,'Tel-Aviv'),
 (805,'Tamra'),
 (806,'Nahriya'),
 (808,'Qiryat-yam'),
 (810,'Tal Al')

 insert into workers VALUES
(1234,'Ran','Synko',443987871,'052-9890987',800),
(1567,'Ahmad','Amir',66434523,'052-9890987',802),
(5532,'Samir','Nizar',23623626,'052-9890987',805),
(7786,'Nizar','Jakov',53535312,'052-9890987',802),
(9099,'Ali','Yousef',12515161,'052-9890987',808),
(1141,'Adon','Hmado',12616335,'052-9890987',805),
(8865,'Yaan','lev',724723623,'052-9890987',802),
(9991,'Moaid','Ronaldo',734734734,'052-9890987',802),
(9921,'Alex','Barlev',443944471,'052-9890987',810)

insert into managers VALUES
(90001,'khaled','ayman',804),
(90002,'Ayman','Dada',802),
(90004,'Saleh','Amir',810),
(90005,'Yiki','Friki',810),
(90006,'Nano','Rano',800),
(90100,'Pizza','Bolos',808),
(90101,'Homos','Ninar',804)

insert into mahlakot  VALUES
(100,'SmartPhones','phone',90004),
(102,'Derit Sims','phone',90004),
(103,'Computers','devices',90001),
(104,'PartsComps','devices',90001),
(105,'Tvs&video','TV',90101),
(106,'SchoolGlasser','pupils services',90002),
(107,'Electra Devs','Electronic',90005),
(108,'DataCenter Webs','Website',90006),
(109,'Other','.)..',90100)

insert into products VALUES
(1002003004001,'LG SmartPhone',100,1500),
(1002003004002,'iPhone Apple x',100,890),
(1012003004005,'WatchSoirt Apple x',100,2300),
(1022322000012,'Toshiba Laptop 500gb',103,1567),
(1020202030304,'Motherboard Gigabyte',104,900),
(1030405060707,'Panosonic Tele Plasma',105,560),
(1055998988989,'Panosara Video Cast',105,230),
(1055040400404,'DataCer Arduino U',107,100),
(5884949598595,'HardDisk SSD 600G',104,800)


insert into Coustmers Values
(10,'Ahmad','Ayoub','2017-06-06',9099,1055998988989),
(11,'Sys','Hmado','2017-06-06',1141,1002003004001),
(12,'Hram','Sleman','2017-06-06',1234,1002003004002),
(13,'Moustafa','AlAmir','2017-06-06',9921,5884949598595),
(14,'Mariam','AlAmir','2017-06-06',9099,1022322000012),
(15,'Daha','Wlilazasja','2017-06-06',9099,1012003004005),
(16,'Yakov','Anjilika','2017-06-06',7786,1055998988989),
(17,'itsik','diri','2017-06-06',9099,1002003004001),
(18,'firas','diri','2017-06-06',1141,1002003004001)
```

with this SQL query

Answer (score 2):

Change `Product_Id` to `bigint` to support values that size.

Rextester demo with corrected code: http://rextester.com/IQE74281

---

To support numbers like: `1002003004001` it would be best to use `bigint` or `decimal/numeric`.

```
+-----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+
| Data type |                                  Range                                   | Storage |
+-----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+
| bigint    | -2^63 (-9,223,372,036,854,775,808) to 2^63-1 (9,223,372,036,854,775,807) | 8 Bytes |
| int       | -2^31 (-2,147,483,648) to 2^31-1 (2,147,483,647)                         | 4 Bytes |
| smallint  | -2^15 (-32,768) to 2^15-1 (32,767)                                       | 2 Bytes |
| tinyint   | 0 to 255                                                                 | 1 Byte  |
+-----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+
```

Reference:

- [int, bigint, smallint, and tinyint (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql)
- [decimal and numeric (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql)

Comment: I have error when `cast(a.Zip as nvarchar(10)` and fix it by `cast(cast(a.Zip as bigint) as nvarchar(10))`